# FileSystemWatcher and rsync

Tags: linux, .net-core

I have a problem, I have a simple application on ubuntu in .net core 2.0, that fires events when something changed in catalogue (new file, delete file etc). Well logic is pretty simple.

```
    public void InitDirectoryWatcher()
    {
        logger.Info($"Directory {rootPath} is being watched");
        Console.WriteLine($"Directory {rootPath} is being watched");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(rootPath);

        fileSystemWatcher.Created += OnCreated;
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        fileSystemWatcher.Error += OnError;

        fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;

        fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

And it works if i do operation through ftp, scp or simple local cop delete file. But now It seems I have stumbled upon a rock i have used rsync to add some files to watched directory, but no event has fired, any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring for renames? IIRC rsync likes to move files into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like i was able to catch rename event as it was said in a comment. So Ive just added:

```
fileSystemWatcher.Rename += OnRename;
```

Event, and i can live with that :)